# Word for code/applications that call an API library

Tags: single-word-requests, computing, software

I have an API library, what do I call code/applications that use it? I want to avoid "client" because in my context, it is ambiguous with another concept.

Also it doesn't have to be a single word, as long as it's short and not awkward to repeat a lot of times in a formal document.

Comment: Personally, I would use *calling code* if you can't use *client.*

Comment: Or *calling processes*.

Comment: One word for "codes/applications that calls" is *ungrammatical*. (^_^) Editing...

Answer (score 2):

In a document that is truly formal, you can invent your own word and put it into the glossary. When it first appears in your document, write it in *italics* and give a definition. Then after that use that word consistently.

"The program which calls this API, hereafter referred to as the *caller*, etc."

Comment: By formal, I don't mean like a legal document. It's more like a business/professional document. But it's a good suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: You've never seen an engineering document in which terms are introduced in this way? What do you think of caller, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is **calling code**.

Answer (score 0):

From a technical point of view an API define a contract between a `caller` and a `callee`.

Comment: any reference that these terminology is accepted/formal?

Comment: As far as I know this convention comes from telecommunications standards : `caller` references the calling party, `callee` the called party.

API of most (all) programming languages expose a caller property which references the component which called a function.

Comment: From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention : "between the caller and the callee", "receive parameters from their caller", etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about "the invoking component", or "invoker"?